# Intersection of two `unordered_set`s in C++ "not working" when in a class method but works with `set`?

Tags: c++, c++11, set, unordered-set

What I have here is two "maps", `xs` and `ys`, which I use to store "points" in a grid.
I also have an array `std::pair<int,int> arr`, such that `xs[x]` returns all the indices in `arr` with x-coordinate `x`, and `ys[y]` returns all indices with y-coordinate `y`.

Let us have the following:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<size_t>> xs {
    {3, {2, 0}},
    {11, {1}}
};
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<size_t>> ys {
    {2, {2 ,1}},
    {10, {0}}
};

std::unordered_set<size_t> intersection;
std::set_intersection(xs[3].begin(), xs[3].end(),
    ys[2].begin(), ys[2].end(),
    std::inserter(intersection, intersection.begin()));
std::cout << intersection.size() << std::endl; // should return 1

intersection.clear();
std::set_intersection(xs[11].begin(), xs[11].end(),
    ys[2].begin(), ys[2].end(),
    std::inserter(intersection, intersection.begin()));
std::cout << intersection.size() << std::endl; // should return 1
```

They do return `1` and `1`. No surprises there.

Let us now isolate the intersection counter in a function:

```cpp
size_t count_intersection(const std::pair<int,int>& pt,
        const std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<size_t>>& xs,
        const std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<size_t>>& ys) {
    
    const int x = pt.first, y = pt.second;

    // Omitted some error checking

    std::unordered_set<size_t> intersection;
    std::set_intersection(xs.at(x).begin(), xs.at(x).end(),
        ys.at(y).begin(), ys.at(y).end(),
        std::inserter(intersection, intersection.begin()));

    return intersection.size();
}
```

```cpp
std::cout << count_intersection({3, 2}, xs, ys) << std::endl;
std::cout << count_intersection({11, 2}, xs, ys) << std::endl;
```

So far, so good.

Now, let's isolate all of this in a class:

```cpp
class Counter {

    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> _pts;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<size_t>> _xs;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_set<size_t>> _ys;

public:
    void add(const std::pair<int,int>& pt) {
        const int x = pt.first, y = pt.second;
        const size_t ind = _pts.size();

        _pts.push_back(pt);
        _xs[x].insert(ind);
        _ys[y].insert(ind);
    }

    size_t count(const std::pair<int,int>& pt) {
        std::unordered_set<size_t> intersection;
        const int x = pt.first, y = pt.second;

        std::set_intersection(_xs[x].begin(), _xs[x].end(),
            _ys[y].begin(), _ys[y].end(),
            std::inserter(intersection, intersection.begin()));
        return intersection.size();
    }
};

int main() {
    Counter c;
    c.add({3,10}); // ind == 0
    c.add({11,2}); // ind == 1
    c.add({3,2});  // ind == 2

    // By this point,
    // _xs == {3: {0, 2}, 11: {1}}
    // _ys == {10: {0}, 2: {1,2}}
    std::cout << c.count({3,2}) << std::endl;  // Should return 1
    std::cout << c.count({11,2}) << std::endl; // Should return 1
}
```

Instead, what I got is

```
1
0
```

However, when I replaced `std::unordered_set` with `std::set`, the result becomes expected.

What's up with `std::unordered_set`?

By the way, my command in compiling is

```sh
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 -pedantic -fsanitize=address -o main.out main.cpp && ./main.out
```

and my `g++ --version` is `g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`.

Comment: You cant do a set intersection of two unordered containers.  The logarithmic complexity guarantees require sorted data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::set_intersection` requires ordered elements.

`unordered_map` and `_set` does not provide ordered elements.

Comment: "...consisting of elements that are found in both sorted ranges `[first1, last1)` and `[first2, last2)`.", from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection). I did not catch that. Thanks!